# If statement matching SSID/network name to String not working

Tags: java, android, regex, android-wifi, ssid

I'm having a strange problem with my code that I cannot figure out, although i'm sure it must be something simple. I've got an if statement in my code that compares the currently connected network name to a string. The problem i'm having is that it does not execute the code within the if statement even if the SSID matches the string, i've logged the current network name so i could check myself that it does match. I've named my network "1" in an attempte to simplify things when it first didn't work with the original network name.
if anyone's got any ideas, let me know :) thanks
code:

```
        ConnectivityManager connMgr = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        mWifi = connMgr.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);

        WifiManager wifiMgr = (WifiManager) ActivityZoneControl.this.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
        WifiInfo wifiConInfo = wifiMgr.getConnectionInfo();
        wifiName = wifiConInfo.getSSID()

        Log.i(debugLOG, wifiName);

        if (wifiName.equals("1")){
             //do something
        }

        else {
            // do something else
        }
```

Log:
[image: log]

Comment: I see, what's the best way to check this? log?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your log output, it seems your SSID string has quote characters included in it:

[image]

Consider using this test instead:

```
if (wifiName.equals("\"1\"")){
```

Comment: Kicking myself that I did not notice this!! Works perfectly now, thank you! I'll accept this as the answer when I can

Comment: @Nun'eChai I wouldn't use contains, that'll break if you have names like 11.